# how to decrease number by using var

Tags: javascript

I have a variable equal to number, so I want decrease this variable value every second.
in this code it is print the same number over and over, although I have written
(n--)

```js
 var x = setInterval(function() {
    var n = 50;
    console.log(n--);
   }, 1000);
```

my question how I can decrease it?

Comment: *by using the variable not the number.* What does this mean? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: @gurvinder372 I mean if I change the value of the var, code still working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And here is one without the need of a global variable but using [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
var x = setInterval(
  (startValue => () => {
    console.log(startValue--);
  })(100),
  1000
);
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) with a closure about the value. Tha advantage is to use a local variable without polluting the global space.

```js
var x = setInterval(function(n) {
        return function() {
            console.log(n--);
        };
    }(100), 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this: it will stop when x will equals to zero

```js
var x = 100;
    
var handler = setInterval(function(){
    x--;
    console.log(x);

    if(x === 0)
        clearInterval(handler)
} , 1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code issue is that you put the `--` sign after and It should be before`(--n)` and It also you have declared `var n = 50`  inside to loop of setInterval, at this way each time that It's executed n variable always is 50, you should to put this varible at the start of yout code.

```js
var n = 50;
var x = setInterval(function() {        
  console.log(--n);
}, 1000);
```