# Understanding IIFE and why it's necessary here

Tags: javascript

In the [IIFE docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE), it talks about using IIFE's for:

> We would also use IIFE to create private and public variables and methods.

And it gives this example:

```js
const makeWithdraw = balance => (function(copyBalance) {
  let balance = copyBalance; // This variable is private
  let doBadThings = function() {
    console.log("I will do bad things with your money");
  };
  doBadThings();
  return {
    withdraw: function(amount) {
      if (balance >= amount) {
        balance -= amount;
        return balance;
      } else {
        return "Insufficient money";
      }
    },
  }
})(balance);

const firstAccount = makeWithdraw(100); // "I will do bad things with your money"
console.log(firstAccount.balance); // undefined
console.log(firstAccount.withdraw(20)); // 80
console.log(firstAccount.withdraw(30)); // 50
console.log(firstAccount.doBadThings); // undefined; this method is private
const secondAccount = makeWithdraw(20); // "I will do bad things with your money"
console.log(secondAccount.withdraw(30)); // "Insufficient money"
console.log(secondAccount.withdraw(20));  // 0
```

However, I don't understand at all why an IIFE is necessary here. It seems the exact same thing can be done with:

```js
  function makeWithdraw(copyBalance) {
      let balance = copyBalance;
      let doBadThings = function() {
        console.log("I will do bad things with your money");
      };
      doBadThings();
      return {
        withdraw(amount) { return (balance < amount) ? "Insufficient money" : (balance -= amount, balance)}
      }
  }


  const firstAccount = makeWithdraw(100); // "I will do bad things with your money"
  console.log(firstAccount.balance); // undefined
  console.log(firstAccount.withdraw(20)); // 80
  console.log(firstAccount.withdraw(30)); // 50
  console.log(firstAccount.doBadThings); // undefined; this method is private
  const secondAccount = makeWithdraw(20); // "I will do bad things with your money"
  console.log(secondAccount.withdraw(30)); // "Insufficient money"
  console.log(secondAccount.withdraw(20));  // 0
```

Is there something I'm missing here in what the IIFE does here that the normal function would not, or why is this used as an example? I understand the concept of closures, but couldn't a closure just as easily be accomplished with:

```js
'use strict';
function closure() {
  console.log('init closure...');
  let privateVar = 1;
  return {
    func1() {console.log('func1...', privateVar)},
    func2() {console.log('func2...', privateVar)},
  }
}
let f = closure();
f.func1();
f.func2();
f.privateVar; // undefined
```

Comment: The whole point is the variables declared and initialized *in the outer closure function* that remain available to the returned functions. Your last example doesn't involve `privateVar` at all.

Comment: @Pointy right, updated. I meant the necessity of using the IIFE though at all.

Comment: a good examle is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48517938/1447675).

Comment: @David542 it's extremely important to keep in mind that JavaScript has changed **a lot** in the last 6 or 7 years.

Comment: @Pointy -- yea...I'm just learning it now so I also have barely any idea about its history.

Comment: Appears to be another case of MDN's quality declining. It absolutely makes no sense here. Given the text talks about the module pattern, the code might originally have been just `const account = (function(balance) { …; return …; })(100);`.